# 80 tickets sold, buy 5; probability of winning all 3 prizes?

Tags: probability

Tegan buys 5 tickets in a raffle in which 80 tickets are sold. There are 3 prizes.
Use a tree diagram to find the probability that Tegan: 
￼a) wins all 3 prizes

I just need help with a)

So this is what I did. Since there are three prizes, I divided (80 / 2).

I then did (5 / (80 / 3)) + (4 / (79/3)...etc until one ticket was left but my answer was off..help pls

Answer (score 2):

For the first prize, you have a 5/80 probability of winning. For the second prize, you have 4/79 probability. For the last prize, you have 3/78. Since all of these actions have to occur, multiply the probabilities to get 60/492960. Simplify and you get 1/8216.

Answer (score 0):

Same answer as RK01 ---- different approach

There are $\binom{80}{3} = 82160 $ ways of picking three tickets from a possible eighty tickets.

There are $\binom{5}{3} = 10 $ ways of picking three tickets from five tickets that you have.

Thus the probability of you winning the three prizes is $\large\frac{10}{82160} = \frac{1}{8216}$